# NSDocumentDirectory giving strange directory as output

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I'm trying to open sqlite database from my documents directory:

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbFileName = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DatabaseName.sqlite"];

self.db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbFileName];

self.db.logsErrors = YES;

self.db = _db;
if ([self.db open]) {
    NSLog(@"database opened");

}
NSLog(@"docDir = %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",docDir,dbFileName]);
```

NSLog shows strange path `docDir` = `/Users/userName/Documents/Users/userName/Documents/DatabaseName.sqlite` instead of `/Users/userName/Documents/DatabaseName.sqlite`. While opening there are no errors or warnings.

After this I tried get count(*) from my table

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT count(*) FROM histories"];
FMResultSet *result = [self.db executeQuery:queryString];
NSLog(@"count = %i", [result intForColumnIndex:0]);
```

Database has more when 10k rows but NSLog shows 0. Application is not for iOS, only Command Line. Where can I find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
docDir = /Users/userName/Documents
dbFileName = /Users/userName/Documents/DatabaseName.sqlite
```

therefore in

```
NSLog(@"docDir = %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",docDir,dbFileName]);
```

the `docDir` is printed twice (`dbFileName` already contains `docDir`).

*Remark:* The statement `self.db = _db;` looks suspicious, you might want to remove that.

**Added:** The FMDB documentation states:

> You must always invoke `-[FMResultSet next]` before attempting to access
>   the values returned in a query, even if you're only expecting one.

So your code probably should look like this:

```
FMResultSet *result = [self.db executeQuery:queryString];
if ([result next]) {
    NSLog(@"count = %i", [result intForColumnIndex:0]);
}
```

Comment: @RomanHouse: I don't know (-: - Have you removed `self.db = _db;`?

Comment: Yes, removed this line, but still 0.